# Nodejs: Pass function as an argument to another function in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two javascript modules. I need to pass a function argument to another file. But am getting `reference error foo is not defined` in line3. Please help.

1.test1.js

```
exports.foo= function foo(x){ //line1
// do something
}

test2 = require("test2") // line2
test2.bar(foo) //line3
```

2.test2.js

```
exports.bar= function bar(foo){
  foo(123)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in line1 of test1.js:

```
exports.foo= function foo(x){
```

where `function foo(x){...` is a function *expression*.

Named function expressions do not create a function declaration of the same name, and the name supplied is only available inside the expression. (Possibly with the exception of some ancient versions of IE about which I care nothing)

You could either create foo as a function declaration and assign it:

```
function foo() { ... code }
exports.foo = foo;
```

or call it in line 3 as `test2.bar(exports.foo)`

Answer (score -1):

use the following approach

module.exports = function foo(x){

//implementation

}

Answer (score -1):

You should assign the function to a variable.

```
const foo = function foo(x){
    // do something
}

test2 = require("./test2")
test2.bar(foo)
```